# Android - Interactive ImageViews

Tags: android, imageview, android-custom-view

I have an image that have several portions inside that are supposed to become selectable.

The task is that user will tap on specific small portion of image and that location is recorded and sent back to a callback somehow.

[image: sample image to be made interactive]

I am at very initial planning stage with this app, so there is no code examples whatsoever.

p.s. if this does not lie under stackoverflow forum, please suggest where I can post it and get the fastest response possible.

Comment: that `"specific small portion of image"` are only rectangles?

Comment: pretty much yes, but they can get varying corner radius and size

Comment: then you have to use `android.graphics.Path` to make it work - the easiest way is to use a format used by a `VectorDrawable` for defining particular paths

Comment: once time ago i wrote a custom `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape` that parses such a `VectorDrawable`: ~80 lines of code which draws the paths and checks what path is at some (x, y) point

Comment: can you guide to a specific example, that ll be really great...I am also thinking of the same way, parsing vector shapes as interactive spaces, but not sure how we can do that

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/raw/DhcQFSLa, `maskId` is a vector drawable id - `R.drawable.some_vector`

Comment: of course you can speed up `getLayersAt` method and quit the loop after finding the first `Layer` if you are sure that layers are not overlapping each other